# Is there a way to declare or store custom helpers in asp.net mvc5 publicly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a custom helper in ASP.NET MVC 5. The following is the code:

**Razor Syntax:**

```
@helper ListCountries(string[] items, string selected)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control">
            @foreach (string str in items)
            {
                if (@str == selected)
                {
                    <option selected="selected">@str</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option>@str</option>
                }
            }

        </select>
    </div>
}
```

**Applying the Helper:**

@ListCountries(ViewBag.Countries, ViewBag.Selected)

**This is the code in my controller:**

```
string[] list = { "USA","UK","India","UAE" };
ViewBag.Countries = list;
ViewBag.Selected = "India";
return View();
```

What I need is, I wanted to store the helper declaration given above (Razor Syntax) in a common place like a .js or .css file so that it can be referred from any page. Any idea?

- Sarin Gopalan

Comment: What is the point of that helper? - just use the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper which actually does it correctly

Comment: The helper actually lists country names. I don't want to put it in the model so I had to create a helper for the same. In the future I can get the flag images via jquery for the same helper.

Comment: If you want to (cringe) use `ViewBag`, then use it with the `@Html.DropDownList()` method.

Comment: Yes! That's a good idea...